# Why is $\sin \theta$ just $\theta$ for a small $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

When $\theta$ is very small, why is sin $\theta$ taken to be JUST $\theta$?

Comment: We have that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ so that $\sin x$ is close to $x$ when $x$ is small.

Comment: Put your calculator in *radian mode*. Calculate $\sin\theta$ for various smallish $\theta$. You will be impressed by how close it is to $\theta$.

Comment: $x-\frac{x^3}{6}<\sin x < x$ when $x$ is small.

Comment: This is only true when the angle is measured in radians.  Radians are defined for the sake of making the statement true.

Comment: here θ is in radian or degrees?for this rule/principle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It's not **just** $\theta$.

What you observe is the fact that $\sin \theta$ and $\theta$ approach zero from either side of the number line at a *pretty similar* rate. This can be best demonstrated with a graph.

[image]

You can see that they are about to overlap just at zero. So when $\sin \theta$ is approaching $0$ for some very very small $\theta$ we can approximate it as $\theta$.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

**=== Geometric ===**

[image: Small angle triangle.svg]

.

The red section on the right, d, is the difference between the lengths of the hypotenuse, H, and the adjacent side, A. As is shown, H and A are almost the same length, meaning cos θ is close to 1 and $\theta^2/2$ helps trim the red away.
:

$\cos{\theta} \approx 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2}$

The opposite leg, O, is approximately equal to the length of the blue arc, s. Gathering facts from geometry, s = A*θ, from trigonometry, sin θ = O/H and tan θ = O/A, and from the picture, $ O \approx s $ and $ H \approx A $ leads to:

:$\sin \theta = {O\over H}\approx{O\over A} = \tan \theta = {O\over A} \approx {s\over A} = {{A*\theta}\over A} = \theta$.

Simplifying leaves,

:$\sin \theta \approx \tan \theta \approx \theta$.

Comment: What's going on with all these downvotes?

Comment: @Jack M Look at the original version of the answer...!